# Select maximum and minium values from multiple columns in single row in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have following table

| id | column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 | 1000 | 4000 | 3000 |
| 2 | 6000 | 7000 | 8000 | 1000 |
| 3 | 8000 | 10000 | 7000 | 4000 |

I want to get max and min values from multiple columns in single row using mysql query

So in short I need following output

| max_value | min_value |
| --- | --- |
| 10000 | 1000 |

Answer (score 4):

Use the scalar `LEAST` and `GREATEST` functions:

```sql
SELECT id, GREATEST(column1, column2, column3, column4) AS max_value,
           LEAST(column1, column2, column3, column4) AS min_value
FROM yourTable;
```